# Override a template of a Django package

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I override a change_list.html template of  a Django package e.g [Django import export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export), in an existing Django app.

E.g I want to override this package [template](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/main/import_export/templates/admin/import_export/change_list_export.html), this is what I did in my project.

path to the file of my app : `app/templates/import_export/change_list.html`

Below is how am overriding :

```
{% extends 'import_export/change_list_export.html' %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
    <div>
        Hello there
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I get this error :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

path to the file of your app : `app/templates/import_export/change_list.html`
this is the path to normal view. Not admin view.

path in git repository: `app/templates/admin/import_export/change_list.html`
this is the path to admin view.

I understand - you use django.admin. In this case you should add `admin` folder in `templates` folder.

Comment: Still getting the same error : `import_export/change_list.html` TemplateDoesNotExist

Answer (score 0):

you must ensure in the settings.py INSTALLED_APP your app name should be listed before the import_export module